# How come when I run a .php script in Ubunutu it just echos the script itself?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have to decode the binary content data of one of my Chrome cache files which I name `cache.log`. The way I am trying to decode it is by using a php script I found here

http://www.frozax.com/blog/2011/05/recover-file-google-chrome-cache-gzipped/

I have installed php with the following command already

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

When I try to run the `index1.php` script I get the following in Terminal

```
s3z@s3z-laptop:~/Desktop$ php index1.php 
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
// cache.log is a copy of chrome cache page with only the file content section
$cacheString = file_get_contents("cache.log");
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\s[0-9a-f]{2}\s/', $cacheString, $matches);
$f = fopen("t.bin","wb");
foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
{
  fwrite($f,chr(hexdec($match)));
}
fclose($f);

ob_start();
readgzfile("t.bin");
$decoded_data=ob_get_clean();
echo $decoded_data;
```

As you can see, all it is doing is echoing the script.

**How do I actually run the script?**

Comment: What looks like PHP is actually output, plain text. Check the syntax of the file and ensure that your code is enclosed in `<?php ... ?>` tags. Please read the manual about PHP's basic syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't look like the code is wrapped in:

```
<?php 

?>
```

If it doesn't have that, it will just echo instead of executing.  The reason for this is that PHP lets you mix server scripting and HTML in the same file.

```
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
    <?php 
        //Inside the php block so it gets executed and prints 'Hello World'
        echo "Hello, World!"; 
    ?>
    <!--Outside the php block so it just gets echoed and prints 'echo "Hello, World!";' -->
    echo "Hello, World!"; 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've got a situation where the code _does_ have the opening `<?php` and closing `?>` but it still only echoes HTML instead of executing the php code. ? (Not Ubunto; via remote shell to a shared host web server--linux version unknown)

Comment: It must be a problem with the script I'm using though, because if I do these commands I get execution output from `phpinfo();` : (1st command:) `echo "<?php phpinfo() ; ?>" > tst_blargh.php` (2nd command:) `php tst_blargh.php` (I don't have to run `chmod +x tst_blargh.php` before the 2nd command to make it executable)